# jquery plugin does not work on multiple elements - options overwritten

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, boilerplate

I've tried to make my first jquery plugin (a lightbox). It works on a single element just the way I want but if I use multiple elements it overwrites my options.

here is my current code. it doesn't seem to work on jsFiddle because of the layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/BjwCm/

you can download the code with a working (failing) sample here:

http://frumbert.org/files/frumbox.zip

I can see that I'm somehow overwrite the options in the default object when I bind to a second object but don't know what i've done wrong. I've tried moving where click is bound but can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this, declared in the outermost closure and used throughout, represents the last element on which FrumBox is instantiated.

Personally, I wouldn't try to fix the code as it stands. Instead adopt [jQuery's "Best Practices" pattern](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). Here's my template based on the example given:

```
(function($){
    // **********************************
    // ***** Start: Private Members *****
    var pluginName = 'xxxxx';
    // ***** Fin: Private Members *****
    // ********************************

    // *********************************
    // ***** Start: Public Methods *****
    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            //"this" is a jquery object on which this plugin has been invoked.
            return this.each(function(index){
                var $this = $(this);
                var data = $this.data(pluginName);
                // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
                if (!data){
                    var settings = {
                    };
                    if(options) { $.extend(true, settings, options); }

                    $this.data(pluginName, {
                        target : $this,
                        settings: settings
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        myMethod_1 : function(){.....},
        myMethod_2 : function(){.....}
    };
    // ***** Fin: Public Methods *****
    // *******************************

    // *****************************
    // ***** Start: Supervisor *****
    $.fn[pluginName] = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist in jQuery.' + pluginName );
        }
    };
    // ***** Fin: Supervisor *****
    // ***************************
})( jQuery );
```

Notes:

- Add further private members and methods as required.
- Public members (methods) are privileged (they have access to private members).
- To maintain chainability, be sure to adopt the `return this.each(function(index){...})` pattern in every method, except any that return a specific value.
- Arguably the hardest aspect of developing with this pattern (and others) is being aware of what `this` refers to in every context. Keep your wits about you.
- Be prepared to use javascript `Function.call()` and `Function.apply` methods. Make sure you understand them.
- The supervisor is difficult to understand at first glance but doesn't need to be
  modified. It is a cool chunk of code.
- Instantiate the plugin on DOM element(s) with `$(selector).pluginNmae()` or `$(selector).pluginNmae(options)`, where `options` is an object literal "map".
- Invoke methods on initialised DOM element(s) with `$(selector).pluginNmae('methodName', ...)`
- An example of this pattern can be found in the [selected answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642992/how-to-make-jquery-ui-tab-blink-flash/9645233#9645233) (including a link to a fiddle).

Comment: Yeah I see that you're correct. I was just coming to the same conclusion. I knew that $this must be being scoped "too high" and as such it would be overwriting the previous setting, therefore screwing it up. Your supervisor also answers what would have been my next question about calling different methods properly.

I really wasn't sure what "the best practice" method was (often debated it seems) - I had looked at a few : https://github.com/zenorocha/jquery-plugin-patterns and took one I recognised reasonably well as a starting point. I think this is what messed me up.

Comment: @frumbert There's certainly no definitive plugin pattern but some are better than others. Thanks for the github link, I hadn't found it before. When I get time I will look through and see what I can learn. I like the pattern I posted above because I trust it but also because I have got used to it. Being a conservative sort, I will probably stick with it for the foreseeable future.

Comment: hmm, my updated code - http://jsfiddle.net/BjwCm/1/ - has problems. My selector is $(".external-links a"); calling open will fire on the last "a" matched not the specific instance.

Comment: Sorry to keep pestering about this, but if you take a look at this new version - http://jsfiddle.net/BjwCm/2/ - I have found that it was executing "each" of the options when using a selector with multiple matches. So I have to perform the each/bind in the caller function (see test case code, bottom of fiddle). This works, but seems "messy", and appears to negate the need for the each inside the plugin. What was the intended use of the inner each in your plugin template?

Comment: In methods, `return $(this).each(function(){...})` iterates through the jQuery selection made with `$(selector).pluginName('methodName')`. Selections are not remembered because the selector may well be different every time `$(selector).pluginName('methodName')` is called.